# I don't understand how this array filter code works?

Tags: javascript

When we use map, what does it reference, the filtered items because its chained to the filter or the original const item?

```
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-time]');
    const filtered =  items.filter(item => textContent.includes('flexbox')).
                            map(item => item.dataset.time);
```

Comment: The filtered items

Comment: Here's the best resource for "chaining/cascading" http://javascriptissexy.com/beautiful-javascript-easily-create-chainable-cascading-methods-for-expressiveness/

Answer (score 0):

The filtered items because its chained to the filter:

```js
const items = [1,3,5,7,9];
const filtered = items.filter(item=>item<6).map(item=>item*2);
console.log(filtered);
```